# Rate of convergence for sample mean of markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

I have 2 finite state, irreducible, aperiodic and reversible Markov chains.
Let say S1 and S2 are the sample means of the chains, and u1 and u2 are the expectations.
I know the Chernoff bound for the rate of convergence between S1 to u1, and S2 to u2 (u1 is bigger then u2), but know I need to find bound for the convergence of:
Pr{((S1-S2)^2)-((u1-u2)^2)">"ε}"<"?
i.e, the convergence rate of the sum (or subtraction) of the sample means, after I know the rate of convergence for each one of them.
Any help with how I can do this?